# Inserting and searching data

Tags: php, mysql, search, input

I have the following array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => &dwA-nTr&
    [1] => @nswt@
    [2] => *DI.2,8*
    [3] => dwA    
    [4] => nTr
    [5] => sp
    [6] => fdw
    [7] => @jHj@
    [8] => *DI.2,9*
    [9] => jHj
    [10] => wr
    [11] => sA
    [12] => Hw,t-Hrw
    [13] => jrj
    [14] => sSS,t
    [15] => n
    [16] => mw,t
    [17] => =f
    [18] => wsr,t
    [19] => @nswt@
    [20] => *DI.2,10*
    [21] => nswt-bj,t.j
```

The goal is to insert this data in a mysql table. Each word starting with '&' is a SCENE; starting with '@' is a DIVINITE and starting with '*' is an ATTESTATION. the other words are regular words. The table has 5 Fields: ID (which is primary key), Word, Attestation, Scene, Divinite. So each regular word has to go in the 'Word' field en the other fields have to be filled with the corresponding info above. So the two first rows should look like this:

```
ID     Word    Attestation    Scene    Divinite
1      dwA      DI.2,8        dwA-nTr   nswt    
2      nTr      DI.2,8        dwA-nTr   nswt
3      sp       DI.2,8        dwA-nTr   nswt
4      fdw      DI.2,8        dwA-nTr   nswt
5      jHj      DI.2,9        dwA-nTr   jHj
6      wr       DI.2,9        dwA-nTr   jHj
7      sA       DI.2,9        dwA-nTr   jHj 
8      Hw,t-Hrw DI.2,9        dwA-nTr   jHj
9      jrj      DI.2,9        dwA-nTr   jHj
10     sSS,t    DI.2,9        dwA-nTr   jHj
11     n        DI.2,9        dwA-nTr   jHj
12     mw,t     DI.2,9        dwA-nTr   jHj
13     =f       DI.2,9        dwA-nTr   jHj
14     wsr,t    DI.2,9        dwA-nTr   jHj
15     nswt-bj,t.j  DI.2,10   dwA-nTr   nswt
```

for this i wrote the following:

```
mysql_select_db("my_db", $con);
$SceneTitle = $InitSceneTitle;
foreach($TextsansBracRenumer as $word)
{
if ($word[0] === "@")    
        {
        $Divinite = str_replace("@", "", $word);
        }
if ($word[0] === "&")    
        {
        $SceneTitle = str_replace("&", "", $word);
        }
if ($word[0] === "*")    
        {
        $position = str_replace("*", "", $word);
        }
else
        {
        $SceneInfo = $position;
        $insert="INSERT INTO Words (Word, Attestation, Scene, Divinite) VALUES ('$word', '$position', '$SceneTitle', '$Divinite')";
        mysql_query($insert) OR die(mysql_error());
}
```

and this is working fine.
But when I want to search the data, trouble starts. 
I wrote the following (table is called Words)

```
mysql_select_db("my_db", $con);
$search = "SELECT Word, Scene, Attestation, Divinite
    FROM Words
    WHERE Word = '$target'  ";

$retval = mysql_query($search, $con);
if(! $retval )
{
die('Could not get data: ' . mysql_error());
}
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($retval, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
echo      
     "{$row['Attestation']} <br> ";
}
```

So for word X  he will give me the attestation. So if I replace $target with the word 'dwA' he will give me 'DI.2,8'
And if I replace the last sentence "{$row['Attestation']} by "{$row['Divinite']} he will give me 'nswt'. and so on.

This works well, but when I want I replace the search

```
$search = "SELECT Word, Scene, Attestation, Divinite
    FROM Words
    WHERE Word = '$target'  ";
```

by

```
  $search = "SELECT Word, Scene, Attestation, Divinite
    FROM Words
    WHERE Scene = '$target'  ";
```

it doesn't work. So if I replace $target with dwA-nTr he should give me twice DI.2,8.
and it doesn't work for Attestation or for Divinite. In fact it only works for Word. 
I try to insert the data manualy and than it works. So it seems not to be in the search program but rather in the way the data is put into the table. 
Does anyone have an idea how to input the data in another manner? so that this would work

I think I found the problem but not the solution. I exported the database with SQL and this is what I get:

```
CREATE TABLE `Words` (
`ID` mediumint(15) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`Word` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
`Attestation` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
`Scene` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
`Divinite` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=22 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `Words`
--

INSERT INTO `Words` VALUES(3, 'dwA', 'DI.2,8\r', 'dwA-nTr\r', 'nswt\r');
INSERT INTO `Words` VALUES(4, 'nTr', 'DI.2,8\r', 'dwA-nTr\r', 'nswt\r');
INSERT INTO `Words` VALUES(5, 'sp', 'DI.2,8\r', 'dwA-nTr\r', 'nswt\r');
INSERT INTO `Words` VALUES(6, 'fdw\r', 'DI.2,8\r', 'dwA-nTr\r', 'nswt\r');
INSERT INTO `Words` VALUES(8, 'jHj', 'DI.2,9\r', 'dwA-nTr\r', 'jHj\r');
INSERT INTO `Words` VALUES(9, 'wr', 'DI.2,9\r', 'dwA-nTr\r', 'jHj\r');
INSERT INTO `Words` VALUES(10, 'sA', 'DI.2,9\r', 'dwA-nTr\r', 'jHj\r');
INSERT INTO `Words` VALUES(11, 'Hw,t-Hrw', 'DI.2,9\r', 'dwA-nTr\r', 'jHj\r');
INSERT INTO `Words` VALUES(12, 'jrj', 'DI.2,9\r', 'dwA-nTr\r', 'jHj\r');
INSERT INTO `Words` VALUES(13, 'sSS,t', 'DI.2,9\r', 'dwA-nTr\r', 'jHj\r');
INSERT INTO `Words` VALUES(14, 'n', 'DI.2,9\r', 'dwA-nTr\r', 'jHj\r');
INSERT INTO `Words` VALUES(15, 'mw,t', 'DI.2,9\r', 'dwA-nTr\r', 'jHj\r');
INSERT INTO `Words` VALUES(16, '=f', 'DI.2,9\r', 'dwA-nTr\r', 'jHj\r');
INSERT INTO `Words` VALUES(17, 'wsr,t\r', 'DI.2,9\r', 'dwA-nTr\r', 'jHj\r');
INSERT INTO `Words` VALUES(19, 'nswt-bj,t.j', 'DI.2,10\r', 'dwA-nTr\r', 'nswt\r');
INSERT INTO `Words` VALUES(21, 'Hnk', 'DI.9,8', 'Hnk-wnHr', 'jHj');
```

as you can see  after each 'Attestation', 'Scene' and 'Divinite' comes a \r. This explains problably why I can search for example the word 'dwA' but not the scene dwA-nTr. but searching on dwA-nTr\r doesn't work either.
BUt as you can see in 21, the row I inserted manualy, this \r is absent

Comment: What is not working? Can you post the real data from the database and not only what it should look like?

Comment: Have you confirmed that the data inserted it correct? Are you manually changing the value of `$target`? Some actual data as a result of your insert commands would be a good start to check, as well as manually running your SQL commands in your SQL client (phpMyAdmin, for example)

Comment: @Nonym: the manual search in phpMyAdmin doesn't work either. if I insert a row manualy, for example 4 - sp(=Word) - DI.8,5(=Attestation) - dwA-nTr(=Scene) - Hr(=Divinite); searching for 'dwA-nTr' and asking attestation  gives me : 'DI.8,5' in fact he should give me all the attestations because all the rows have dwA-nTr in the field 'Scene'. But he gives me only the field 'Attestation' of the row that i inserted manualy. THis made me think that the problem has something to do with the input of the data. If i fill in each row manualy it would work. But the array is too long to put in manualy

Comment: I extended the example of the database, as to have an idea how it looks like, but once again, if I would insert all the data manualy with phpMyAdm, than it works, but this would of course take ages

Answer (score 0):

I'm still studying your post, but can we start with this?:

```
foreach($TextsansBracRenumer as $word)
{ # changed to else..if since $word[0] is only one value, right? let me know
    if ($word[0] === "@")    
    {
    $Divinite = str_replace("@", "", $word);
    }
    else if ($word[0] === "&")    
    {
    $SceneTitle = str_replace("&", "", $word);
    }
    else if ($word[0] === "*")    
    {
    $position = str_replace("*", "", $word);
    }
}
# just imagining pulling this out of your code, assuming that the foreach above handled the word-processing
$SceneInfo = $position;
$insert="INSERT INTO Words (Word, Attestation, Scene, Divinite) VALUES ('$word', '$position', '$SceneTitle', '$Divinite')";
mysql_query($insert) OR die(mysql_error());
```

I'd like to ask for more code, like:

what is the value of `$InitSceneTitle` ?
what is the value of `$TextsansBracRenumer` ?

[edit][based on new information : inserted row data]

Try replacing this:

```
$Divinite = str_replace("@", "", $word);
```

With this:

```
$Divinite = str_replace("\n",'', str_replace("\r",'', str_replace("@", "", $word)));
```

It seems that the data in your array contains new line and carriage return characters, represented by `\n` and `\r` respectively.. You'll have to replace those. What this brings to light is... How is the array populated with data? Because if we're not careful, then those two   (\n and \r) might have to or should remain in your data. If that's the case, then we will change our approach.

For now.. do the same for the word, scene, and attestation. And then perform your search again.. Let me know what happens...

Comment: :$TextsansBracRenumer is the name of the array; $InitSceneTitle= ''

Comment: *word[0] is always only one value: &, @ or *. the foreach is indeed the part that inserts the data in the database table.

Comment: That's weird.. Can you post the current data in your table? Your current logic doesn't seem right (that is.. I might be missing something indeed) -- You check if the word starts with `@` or `&` but if none of those are met, you then check for `*` and if you don't find an `*` (forget the rest, because they are not in `else if` enclosures, you then insert. That's why I'm asking for sample data. Because your `INSERT` command is within the `foreach`, I've come to wonder maybe because I, sadly, don't understand it at this time.. Could you echo `$insert` as well before you execute it?

Comment: when a word starts with & it is a Scene, with @  a Divinite and with * an Attestation; when the program encounters a word starting with one of these it stores it as $Divinite, $SceneTitle or $position; when a word doesn't start with one of these signes, than it is stored in the field Word and the other fields are filled with the stored information so $Divinite comes in the field Divinite, and so on . When another word starting with @, & or $ is encountered, it replaces the previous one. this is how in the database, between ID 4 and 5 the Attestation jumps from DI.2,8 to DI.2,9.

Comment: I narrowed the problem down. In fact it is situated higher than what i put int this question. the problem arises when the array is made. The original text is not a continuous text but in lines, which means that the last word of the line is followed by a \r and this is (invisibly) added in the array. So I have to solve the problem a little bit higher up the program. For the moment I close this question; Thanks for the help anyway.